# "Se ti farebbe comodo" o "Se ti facesse comodo"?

Tags: verbs, subjunctive-mood, conditional-mood

Ho scritto: "Se ti farebbe comodo utlizzarlo scrivimi". Ora ho questo dubbio, è scorretto ed andrebbe invece usato "Se ti facesse comodo utlizzarlo scrivimi"? Quella più corretta, anche se troppo lunga e per questo non mi piace, penso sia "Se ti potrebbe far comodo utlizzarlo scrivimi".

Qualcuno potrebbe
illuminarmi?

Comment: Se ti facesse comodo utilizzarlo, scrivimi! - Se ti potesse far comodo utilizzarlo, scrivimi.

Comment: Il ‘se’ + condizionale: quando è possibile? https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/lingua-e-scuola/posta-del-professore/il-se-condizionale-quando-e-possibile/

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: @Hachi: Penso che la fonte che hai individuato ti permetta di scrivere una buona risposta. Potresti farlo, per favore?

Comment: @Charo - scusa non riesco oggi, se nel frattempo vuoi farlo tu o qualcun altro, grazie.

Comment: Aggiungo a margine che “scorretto” è più abituale di “incorretto” che, più che per dire “sbagliato”, si usa per indicare qualcosa che non è (ancora) stato corretto.

Answer (score 5):

Si tratta di un costrutto condizionale in cui si vuole esprimere "se accade o accadesse una certa condizione, allora *scrivimi*".

Sul [portale *Lingua e Scuola*](https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/lingua-e-scuola/posta-del-professore/il-se-condizionale-quando-e-possibile/) della casa editrice Zanichelli si può trovare una spiegazione al dubbio formulato dall'OP:

> Comunque incominciamo col ribadire che la costruzione corretta è: 
>
> se + congiuntivo, condizionale: *se tu fossi più buono, ne sarei felice*
>
> con le varianti
>
>
> se + futuro, futuro: *se sarai buono ne sarò felice*
>
>
> se + presente, presente: *se sei buono ne sono felice*
>
> In nessun caso in frasi condizionali di questo tipo la congiunzione *se* può essere seguita dal condizionale: *se saresti buono* è sbagliato qualunque sia il modo e il tempo che segue.
>
> Invece ‘se’ può essere seguito dal condizionale nei significati **7** e **8** dello Zingarelli: 
>
> **7** Introduce una prop. dubitativa, semplice o disgiuntiva, con il v. al congtv., all’indic. o all’inf.: *vedi se puoi aiutarmi; guarda in libreria se è uscito qualche nuovo libro; tenta se ce la fai o no; vedrò se sia il caso di aiutarlo o se invece sia meglio che si arrangi*.
>
> **8** Introduce una prop. interr. indiretta semplice o disgiuntiva con il v. al congtv., all’indic. o all’inf.: *non so se potrò partire; dimmi se intendi continuare così; domandagli se accetta o no; non so se scrivere o telefonare; non so se sarei capace di mentire* | Con ellissi del v.: *chiedigli quando è in casa, se al mattino o al pomeriggio*; *dimmi cosa scegli, se il cinema o il teatro* | (enfat.) In espressioni escl. o interr. con ellissi della prop. principale: *se sono stanco?, certo che lo sono!*; *se ha pazienza?, moltissima!*; *se è ricco!, altro che!* | In prop. escl., con valore affermativo; per es. in: *‘Lo conoscete voi Brighella?’ ... ‘Oh, se lo conosco!’ *(**C. Goldoni**).
>
>
> Ad esempio nel significato **7** si può dire: *vedi se potrebbe aiutarmi* (e qui potremo senz’altro aggiungere un esempio)
>
>
> Nel significato **8**: *domandagli se accetterebbe o no* (sottinteso: *qualora glielo proponessimo*).

È da sottolineare il fatto che

> in nessun caso in frasi condizionali di questo tipo la congiunzione *se* può essere seguita dal condizionale

Cioè, non si dice **se ti farebbe comodo utlizzarlo* né **se ti potrebbe far comodo utlizzarlo*. Nel caso in studio, come indicato da @Hachi nel suo commento, si dovrebbe dire

> *se ti facesse comodo utilizzarlo, scrivimi!*

oppure

> *se ti potesse far comodo utilizzarlo, scrivimi!*

usando il congiuntivo e non il condizionale.

Ma anche semplicemente, come si vede nella spiegazione sopra citata, si può fare il costrutto condizionale con la struttura "se + presente indicativo, ..." (nel caso in studio si adopera l'imperativo): usando il congiuntivo al posto del presente indicativo si aggiunge una sfumatura di incertezza sulla condizione che appare nella frase:

> *Se ti fa comodo utilizzarlo, scrivimi!*